# sh -c irrationality and programmatically determining and running Linux builtin commands

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I need to, from a program, determine if a Linux command is a builtin. I also need to occasionally run that builtin command. I'll use alias as an example, it applies to other builtins too.

The one apropos answer I found was to use:

```
sh -c 'type alias'
```

This returns 'alias is a shell builtin', exactly what I needed. But...I also need to run it. And nothing I have tried will do so.  All of these fail in a terminal window (and programmatically):

- `sh -c 'alias'` (no output whatsoever)
- `sh -c 'command alias'` (no output whatsoever)
- `sh -c 'builtin alias'` (sh: 1: builtin: not found)
- `sh -c 'type builtin'` (builtin: not found)
- `sh -c 'type command'` (command is a shell builtin)
- `sh -c 'type type'` (type is a shell builtin)

(Almost) needless to say, all these commands (ie., without `sh -c`) work fine from a terminal. This has me confused as to the seemingly irrational nature of `sh -c` commands.

My question is: is this true of all Linux versions? Am I missing a switch or setting? How can I, then, from a program, execute a builtin so as to get its output back?

I'm working on Kubuntu 14.04 (also true in Trisquel); this problem occurs in both `konsole` and `xterm`, and programmatic calls.

---

Thank you for the comments and answers, greatly appreciated.

I do need to clarify what I am doing: I am writing a CLI helper GUI, a program to store favorite linux commands and execute them.

I work with freepascal / Lazarus which has a TProcess class that starts a process and gives access to the stdin, stdout, and stderror.

This works exceptionally well with file-based commands (rsync for example, etc.) and I have no problems inputting and outputting text. I can even reproduce piping simply passing output from on process to input of another. But...

...not so with Builtin's. Which started me on the path of researching alias, etc.

I want my program to also include builtin's but the first problem was how to even tell if it was a builtin when it was added (yes the list of builtin's is limited, but later it could be expanded and I'd like my program to handle that eventuality). Thus I researched and found sh -c 'type cmd'.

Now I can determine whether a command is file based (using which) or builtin (using expression above).

While there won't be a huge call for running builtin's through my program it is occasionally useful to get the output from one. For example, alias. alias when run without params is equivalent to alias -p which simply output's the current aliases registered in the system.

But here is where the snag is. As I've shown above I can't seem to get the output's.

I do now understand the subshell concept and that explains why I'm getting nothing back (I had suspected it was somehow output related).

Unfortunately all suggestions so far do not work. For instance, the eval command (thank you for that I didn't know that one). It is a builtin. So the only way I know to (try to) get the output is with the sh -c 'eval alias', which returns nothing because it is sub-shelled.

So is there a way to get the output of the subshell back to the process I started? Remember I'm doing this programatically through a process I created (but this problem is also reflected in terminal, same thing happens).

I also wanted to comment on some other comments:

Yes I've been thinking about writing out a bash sh file and running that but won't I have the same problem?

Simply running the commands (through my created process) results in an exception because the process doesn't know anything about the shell and so only runs files, builtin's are not found and so fail, which is why the sh -c, or something similar, is my only option.

Why do I need to run alias? Well, it was just an example, like I said this is a builtin problem, I was using alias as the example. But, personally, I like alias and maybe some of my users do too.

One final observation: why does `sh -c 'type alias'` work? if the reason `sh -c 'command alias'` returns no output because it is sub-shelled then why is the `type` version working? Type is special? This is where I see the irrationality.

Comment: `sh -c` opens a subshell with no aliases defined. Thats why it returns nothing. Try `bash -c 'alias "a=blah";alias'`

Comment: You can use the `type` command within a bash script and then programatically decide what to do based on the return string.

Comment: The list of built-ins doesn't vary much.  Why do you think you need to experiment?  Why does it matter whether they're built-ins or not? Simply run the commands — they should work.

Comment: What kind of program are you coding that starts a shell, and how do you start it? In what language is your program written? Please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it (and show the few lines of code from your program and  how exactly you run the commands there).

Comment: Why do you need to run `alias`? Nobody should ever use aliases.

Comment: The reason `sh -c 'command alias`' produces no output is that `command alias` produces no output, and that is because `alias` produces no output.  `type alias` produces output because it is designed to produce a message describing `alias`.

Comment: @tripleee Uh? No, this question is not about separate shell instances vs executing a single shell. Answers saying to use `source` are irrelevant here.

Comment: @Gilles I'm thinking more about the answer with `expand_aliases`.

Comment: @tripleee Completely irrelevant here. The asker isn't even running bash!

Comment: A "CLI helper GUI" shouldn't use a shell -- no `sh -c` or `bash -c` or anything else -- unless you **really** know what you're doing. Shell injection attacks are every bit as much a problem as SQL injection attacks. If your users specify a literal argv array in their configuration, then they can specify a shell if and only if they really want and have cause for one.

Comment: a "CLI helper GUI" should really be some shell. You might make it a plugin for the few shells extendable by plugins.

Comment: Thanks I will keep these suggestions in mind. The initial intention is to  output the help for a command while the user composes a command, and these stored commands to be executed (or copy/pasted into terminal) later. In any case, wouldn't anything coming from my program be subject to permissions just as it is in terminal? I mean I can't format the disk without the user putting in their password. I certainly do not want to endanger anyone's computer, so any insights into why bash -c would be potentially dangerous would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for consistency in the wrong place because you're missing a critical aspect of what some of those commands are doing. Running the same command in different contexts might yield a different result. For example, if you run `ls` or `pwd` (with no arguments), the result depends on the current directory.

The dichotomy isn't between built-in commands and non-built-in commands, but between commands whose behavior are influenced by which shell runs them and commands that aren't. There is a correlation: most commands that are influenced by which shell runs them are built in, because an external command would not be able to access the state of the shell that runs them.

- The command `alias` prints out the lists of aliases defined *in the current shell*. Aliases are part of the internal state of a shell. If you run a new shell instance, it starts out with no aliases defined, so `alias` prints an empty list. Typically, when you're running an interactive shell, your aliases are the ones defined by your startup file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) and that's what `alias` lists. But if you run `alias` or `unalias` on the command line, you can change the aliases of that shell instance, and that doesn't affect other shells (try it out to make sure that you understand what's going on).
- `command alias` does the same thing as `alias` since `alias` is a builtin.
- `builtin alias` does the same thing as `alias` in bash. The `builtin` command is a bash builtin. `builtin` does not exist in other shells; on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is not bash but dash, a shell that's smaller, faster and also POSIX-compliant but lacks some of bash's more advanced features. This also explains `type builtin`. `bash -c 'type builtin'` would report that `builtin` is a builtin.
- `type command` and `type type` report that `command` and `type` are builtins because they are builtins in `sh`.

You can't execute a builtin from a program: a builtin is a command of a particular shell. You can execute a shell that supports this builtin and tell it to execute that builtin, but of course the builtin is executed in the context of that shell.

You can no more execute the `alias` command from a Pascal program than you can call the Pascal `write` function from a shell program. A shell builtin is a library function of the shell. Shells blur the distinction between their own functions and external programs because you can call an external program using the same syntax rather than going through something like the `TProcess` class, but at the end of the day the concepts are the same.

A “CLI helper GUI” already exists: it's called a terminal emulator. It sounds like you want to make some more constrained GUI that can only execute certain specific commands. In that case, I don't think it makes sense to expose features such as aliases. You aren't providing an interface to a shell here, you're providing an interface to run program. You aren't interfacing the shell, you're substituting to it. So don't think of *shell commands*, think of *running programs*. There's no program called `alias`.

Comment: Yessss! Thank you, I'm now clear on the concepts. After digesting your excellent explanation I found the answer! I will post it below.

Answer (score 3):

Well *builtins* are directly executed by the current shell (hence the name...). So if you want to allow commands like `cd` or `alias`, or if you want to allow user to change the environment variables, you will have to explicitely write code for that in you own *shell*.

The only good new, is that some builtins are only integrated into the shell to speed up processing (directly executed without forking a new process) but also exist as actual commands. Try to find them in the path to make sure.

Comment: Yes I've seen that...pwd for example.

Answer (score 2):

When you run some command with `bash -c` or `sh -c` a *new* shell [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is forked. In contrast, when you source (with `source somefile` or `. somefile`) some file, the *current* shell process is reading it (and likewise [for `eval`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/eval)).

Any builtin command like `alias` (or `cd` or `ulimit`) is only affecting the current shell process. So if you run it with `sh -c` only the new shell running it is affected, not your parent shell (the one running in your terminal).

There is no irrationality here. Btw you could try `bash -c 'echo $$'` vs `echo $$` (since `$$` gives the pid of the current shell).

BTW, from inside a (C or C++) program, you might use something like [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Of course, for similar reasons, inside your C program using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), a `system("cd $HOME")` won't work like you want (you need to call [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) directly, perhaps as `chdir(getenv("HOME"))`)

I suggest to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Notice also that both `system` & `popen` are (implicitly) using `/bin/sh -c` (and expecting a POSIX compliant shell) which is not the same as `/bin/bash -c`. Read the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/) and notice that not every shell is an [interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html) (in particular, neither  [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) nor [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) are starting an interactive shell).

Comment: Thank you for the insights, they are helpful. I don't know if you saw my updated question and wonder if you have any insights into this:  why does << sh -c 'type alias' >> work? if the reason sh -c 'command alias' returns no output because it is sub-shelled then why is the "type" version working? Type is special? This is where I see the irrationality.

Comment: Huh? `sh -c 'command alias'` returns no output *because there are no aliases in the shell* (not "subshell", that's a specific term for a different thing). It doesn't stop being a valid command just because its output list when it successfully runs is empty. It's a perfectly valid command, and the empty list is perfectly valid successful output. If it *weren't* running successfully, you'd have an error printed to stderr.

Comment: Think of if you were running `grep foo /dev/null`. That the output is empty doesn't mean that `grep` didn't run. Similarly, your code is successfully running the `alias` command -- in a noninteractive shell (which, thus, doesn't source your `~/.bashrc` [not that you should expect a shell started with `sh -c` rather than `bash -c` to be bash at all]) with no aliases defined.

Comment: All right. You guys officially rock. All is clear now. I found the answer and it works perfectly:  bash -i -c 'command alias'  returns the output, yesssss. Super, thank you all so much. Oh, and pardon me for maybe mixing terms, I'm still in lunux-learn-mode.

Comment: I also wanted to say thanks for the link to advanced linux programming, very informative and I recommend it to other people in linux-learn-mode who read this in future.